# How to set a unique value in an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to push a unique value in an array and I'm using jquery

```
var otNotesTimeIntrArray = new Array();
$("#otNoteFluids").on('change',function() {
   var otNotesTimeIntr = $("#otNotesTimeIntr").val();
   otNotesTimeIntrArray.push(otNotesTimeIntr);
 });
```

otNotesTimeIntr consists of Time intervals. 
Example: 10:15AM, 10:45AM...

If 10:15AM already exist, I don't want it to push into array..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use can use `.indexOf` to check whether a value already exists in an array or not

```
var otNotesTimeIntrArray = new Array();
$("#otNoteFluids").on('change',function() {
   var otNotesTimeIntr = $("#otNotesTimeIntr").val();

   //Use .indexOf before pusing into array
   if(otNotesTimeIntrArray.indexOf(otNotesTimeIntr)==-1)
      otNotesTimeIntrArray.push(otNotesTimeIntr);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if a value exists in an array.

```js
var otNotesTimeIntrArray = new Array();
$("#otNoteFluids").on('change',function() {
   var otNotesTimeIntr = $("#otNotesTimeIntr").val();
   if(!otNotesTimeIntrArray.includes(otNotesTimeIntr))
     otNotesTimeIntrArray.push(otNotesTimeIntr);
 });
```